# capture navigation events from WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview that has some custom HTML loaded into it.  In this HTML there is a link to an image.  Right now when the user clicks the link, it automatically opens the image in the default android browser.  I would instead like to capture that click event and open the URL in my own view as to preserve branding within the UI.

In iOS this is done by using a UIWebViewDelegate, is there something similar for android's WebView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a subclass of `WebViewClient` and override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. Then, attach an instance of that class to your `WebView` via `setWebViewClient()`. This works for simple hyperlinks and server-issued redirects.